# Phaser plugin class is not defined when put in a separate script file?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a phaser plugin for pathfinding, where the class, `PhaserNavMeshPlugin`, is not defined when I have my code like this:

**HTML:**

```
<script src = "phaser.min.js"> </script>
<script src = "my_plugin.js"> </script>
<script src = "my_game_code.js"> </script>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(myConfigFile)

class MyScene extends Phaser.Scene{
     constructor(sceneData){
      super()
     }
    preload(){
     this.load.scenePlugin({
         key: "MyPlugin",
         url: MyPlugin,
         sceneKey: "myPlugin",
     });
    }
    create(){
    //do stuff
    }
    update(){
    //do more stuff
    }
}
```

But when I have my code so that the code from the plugin file is appended at the beginning of `my_game_code.js`, like so, the plugin works fine.

**HTML:**

```
<script src = "phaser.min.js"> </script>
<script src = "my_game_code.js"> </script>
```

**Javascript:**

```
//code pasted from my_plugin.js
var game = new Phaser.Game(myConfigFile)

class myScene extends Phaser.Scene{
     constructor(sceneData){
      super()
     }
    preload(){
     this.load.scenePlugin({
         key: "MyPlugin",
         url: MyPlugin,
         sceneKey: "myPlugin",
   });
   }
    create(){
    //do stuff
    }
    update(){
    //do more stuff
    }
}
```

Having the plugin code at the beginning of the JS file where it is used is a decent temporary solution, but not one that I want to have around any longer than I need to. Any ideas? Thanks!

PS: The plugin is [mikewesthad's navmesh plugin](https://github.com/mikewesthad/navmesh#phaser-navmesh-api-reference), and I'm using Glitch as my editor.

Comment: could you verify, that the cdn solution works for your application?

Comment: Yep, sorry I just saw this. Thanks for all the help with my pathfinding and tilemap woes over the past few weeks, I couldn't have gotten past them without your help. It really means the world to me I could find someone so consistently kind and helpful.

Comment: Thank you, for your kind words. I'm glad I could help. :) I checkout the *phaser-framework* tag on Stackoverflow regularly, when I have time, it helps me learn and get to know phaser better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be, that [glitch.com](https://glitch.com) doesn't allow/like minified files. *([If this article](https://support.glitch.com/t/files-not-working/57246) on the support side is correct)*  Or simply that the [glitch.com](https://glitch.com) editor has problems working with minified files, that are uploaded.

Easy solution, don't minify the code you upload, or in the case of this specific plugin, just load it over a CDN, like this one https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser-navmesh@2.3.1/dist/phaser-navmesh-plugin.min.js. It should work.